# IIS 7.5 HEAD request is not reaching my ashx handler

Tags: iis-7.5, ashx

I must be missing something very simple

HEAD requests to my IIS 7.5 site are receiving a 200 ok response.
But not from my ashx code. My code never sees the request.

How do I find out what is intercepting and handling the HEAD request and make it stop?

Answer (score 0):

Doh!

I was looking for evidence that my handler had processed the HEAD request in the response body. But of course for a head request there is no response body.

All is well the HEAD request is reaching my ashx just fine